# How can I calculate the area of an object by using its contour (chain code)?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, image-processing

Say I have a rotated squared object with chain code [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7] using 8-connectedness. How can I derive its area, as in number of pixels?

EDIT:

I derived the chain code from the boundary pixels. If it is easier to  calculate the area by the boundary pixels, how can this be done?

The algorithm should be able to find the number of pixels enclosed by the boundary (including the boundary pixels). The shape of the boundary can be arbitrary, as long as it is closed and does not intersect with itself.

Comment: Do yo mean you want to calculate the area of a cube?

Comment: No, objects from a black/white image (x,y). As for this example, the answer should be 41. If it had not been rotated, it would be 5*5 = 25

Answer (score 2):

The area of any polygon can be calculated from its vertices using this formula:

```
A = 1/2 Sum(i = 1..n, x[i]*y[i+1] - x[i+1]*y[i])
```

Source: [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html)

Comment: Check your formula for non-rotated square 2x2  ;-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: For a non rotated 2x2 square with the vertices `{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 2}, {0, 2}}` I get the area 4. Seems right to me.

Comment: How you derived such coordinates from chain code `[0, 2, 4, 6]`?

Comment: @nikie: This formula gives a mathematically correct area, but I need the number of pixels...

Answer (score 1):

[image: formula]
where
n - number of border pixels,
(x_k, y_k) - coordinates of k-th border pixel (derived from your chain code by assuming x_1=0, y_1=0),
(n+1)-th pixel is the first pixel.

Comment: @denver - Reference to what?  I've derived this formula by myself.

Comment: Where does the n+2 come from?

Comment: @nikie - It's area of the frame around the polygon formed by centers of border pixels.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: This formula does not give a general solution to arbitrary non-intersecting closed contours

Comment: If you derived it yourself then can you provide your derivation.

Comment: @Skogen - Yes, it does give a general solution.  Do you have an counterexample?

Answer (score 0):

See [Wikipedia: Pick's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem).

This is an extraordinary result, which applies only if the vertices have integral co-ordinates in some representation of the plane. I think this is true in your case. If it is, it provides a very simple way of calculating the area.

Comment: Not simple at all ! Because you know the number of outline points, which is simply the length of the Freeman chain, but you don't know the number of inside points. To find these, you might draw the outline and use seed filling, or perform direct polygon filling, but this is way more complex that the shoelace formula, and much less efficient.